# Decrease Lag When Scrolling Throught Views With Large Background Images

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Large background images within scroll views are apparently very laggy, I've tried compressing the images, but that doesn't seem to change anything. Is there any way to decrease the scrolling lag? Any answers are appreciated, thanks!

And here is my XML layout...

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:id="@+id/day_switcher"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/day_holder"
        android:layout_width="8000dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout // Has Large Background Image
            android:id="@+id/day_left"
            android:background="some_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <include
                layout="@layout/day_view_1" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout // Has Large Background Image
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/day_left"
            android:background="some_background"
            android:id="@+id/day_mid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <include
                layout="@layout/day_view_2" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout // Has Large Background Image
            android:id="@+id/day_right"
            android:background="some_background"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/day_mid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <include
                layout="@layout/day_view_3" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: first of all: what are the resolutions of your images?

Comment: Try reducing your view heirarchy. Its too messy

Comment: @BartekLipinski I'm guessing 1080 by 3000

Comment: Did you try this xml without images? Maybe your problem is not images.

Comment: @invisbo No, it work fine without the images. It also works fine with 1 background image, but not all 3

Comment: @Axonshi123 there you go, there is your problem. Three 1080x3000 images loaded into the memory at the same time must mess your app.

Comment: tbh one image that big in the memory could already mess your app. Why such big images?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to find your problem but here're a few tips which may help.

1- Try to use small images.

2- You can use a image library for reduce image size and manage view operation.

Here're a few image libraries:

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

http://square.github.io/picasso/

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

http://frescolib.org

3- You can reduce your layout's depth. You include layouts. It may cause to increase depth of your layout. You can check the usage of `merge` tag.

Edit:

4- @pskink: RelativeLayout with android:layout_width="8000dp" and drawing huge image is a culprit.

Comment: #3 sounds like the best answer.  I mean his app is already 4 levels deep without even getting into the included layouts.  4 levels should be near the maximum total depth.  And I doubt his included layouts are any better.

Comment: savepopulation, his `RelativeLayout` with `android:layout_width="8000dp"` and drawing huge image is a culprit, layout's depth has little impact only once (when in initial measure / layout phase) since when scrolling neither `onMeasure` nor `onLayout` are called

Comment: @pskink by the way i think layout depth also has an effect on findViewById performance.

Comment: when scrolling? who calls `findViewById ` when scrolling?

Comment: no not scrolling of course. just put a note for who reads these comments. (maybe scrolling a list view which does not use holder pattern :))